# How find IP adress of a lost Bridge

Tags: windows, networking, router, bridge

This is my network : (Yellow : Wifi and Green : Cable)

[image]

My PC 3 can't obtain the IP address by DHCP because the BRIDGE 1 is LOST. I need to fix a static IP.
Before, BRIDGE 1 had a static IP address 192.168.1.253 and it worked.
I don't know how but the BRIDGE 1 lost its configuration.

I already scan 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255 and I don't find BRIDGE 1.

How can I find BRIDGE 1?